# Go application making SQL Query using GROUP_CONCAT on FLOATS returns []uint8 instead of actual []float64

Tags: sql, go

Have a problem using group_concat in a query made by my go application.

Any idea why a group_concat of FLOATS would look like a []uint8 on the Go side?

Cant seem to properly convert the suckers either.

It's definitely floats, I can see it in the raw query results, but when I do the same query in go and try to .Scan the result, Go complains that it's a `[]uint8` not a `[]float64` (which it actually is) Attempts to convert to floats gives me the wrong values (and way too many of them).

For example, at the database, I query and get 2 floats for the column in question, looks like this:

```
"5650.50, 5455.00"
```

On the go side however, go sees a `[]uint8` instead of `[]float64`. Why does this happen? How does one workaround this to get the actual results?

My problem is that I have to use this SQL with the `group_concat`, due to  the nature of the database I am working with, this is the best way to get the information, and more importantly the query itself works great, returns the data the function needs, but now I cant read it out because of type issues. No stranger to those, but Go isn't cooperating with me today.

I'd be more than pleased to learn WHY go is doing it this way, and delighted to learn of a way to deal with it.

Example:

```
SELECT ID, getDistance(33.1543,-110.4353, Loc.Lat, Loc.Lng) as distance,
GROUP_CONCAT(values) FROM stuff INNER JOIN device on device.ID = stuff.ID WHERE (someConditionsETC) GROUP BY ID ORDER BY ID
```

The actual result, when interfacing with the actual database (not within my application), is

```
"5650.00, 5850.50"
```

It's clearly 2 floats.

The same result produces a slice of uint8 when queried from Go and trying to .Scan the result in. If I range through and print those values, I get way more than 2, and they are `uint8` (bytes) that look like this:

```
53,55,56,48,46,48,48
```

Not sure how Go expects me to handle this.

Solution.... stupid simple and not terribly obvious:

The solution:

```
crazyBytes := []uint8("5760.00,5750.50")
    aString := string(crazyBytes)
strSlice := strings.Split(aString,",") // string representation of our array (of floats)
var floatz []float64
for _, x := range strSlice {
    fmt.Printf("At last, Float: %s \r\n",x)
    f,err := strconv.ParseFloat(x,64)
    if err != nil { fmt.Printf("Error: %s",err) }
    floatz = append(floatz, f)
    fmt.Printf("as float: %s \r\n", strconv.FormatFloat(f,'f',-1,64))
}
```

Yea sure, it's obvious NOW.

Comment: Have you tried to do some research before posting this question???  I'm pretty sure if you Google "mysql converting float to int", there are tons of example.

Comment: Yea, that would be very useful, if that was what I was trying to do.

Comment: Every value is transmitted as a []uint8 (an alias for []byte) from the database, and the driver then decodes them into Go types. Types that are not natively supported by the driver have to implement [sql.Scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner). If you want a concrete answer, add the code that scans the result set, including all relevant types.

Comment: I've been looking for an implementation example of sql.Scanner after reading the same, haven't found one that made any sense yet. Everyone says "just implement sql.Scanner" no one talks about how to do that. Anyways, thanks for your answer, I'm adding my solution to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT returns a string. So in Go you get a byte array of characters, not a float. The result you posted `53,55,56,48,46,48,48` translates into a string "5780.00" which does look like one of your values. So you need to either fix your SQL to return floats or use strings and strconv modules in Go to parse and convert your string into floats. I think the former approach is better, but it is up to you.

Comment: Thanks again, you did actually seem to hit the root of the issue, GROUP_CONCAT returns a string, and I cant avoid using it in this query.....

I expected an array/slice. The []byte slice makes sense now, I'm just glad I figured out []byte was my bastard string, parsing it out from there was trivial.